# How to replace this triple For loop with a single numpy array operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, graph-theory

For a turn based game I would like to compute the maximum number of units each player can move or spawn on each zone of a map.

All the datas I need to compute this are already stored in several numpy arrays but I'm struggling to find the advanced array indexing techniques to do the computation as fastest as possible.

To help figure out this problem, I've rewritten the function in the simplest way with some For loops:

```
import numpy as np

def get_max_units_on_zone_per_player(unitCountPerPlayer, zoneOwner, playerAvailableUnits, zoneLinks, blockedMovesPerPlayer):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    unitCountPerPlayer: np.array((zoneCount, playerCount), dtype=int)
        How many units each player has on a zone
    zoneOwner: np.array(zoneCount, dtype=int)
        Which player is owning a zone (-1 for none)
    playerAvailableUnits: np.array(playerCount, dtype=int)
        How many units each player can spawn
    zoneLinks: np.array((zoneCount, zoneCount), dtype=int)
        > 0 if zone1 is connected to zone2 (directed and weighted graph)
    blockedMovesPerPlayer: np.array((playerCount, zoneCount, zoneCount), dtype=bool)
        True if player can not move from zone1 to zone2

    Returns
    -------
    np.array((zoneCount, playerCount), dtype=int)
        Maximum count of units each player can have on each zone
    """

    zoneCount, playerCount = unitCountPerPlayer.shape

    # Adding units already on zone
    result = np.zeros((zoneCount, playerCount), dtype=int) + unitCountPerPlayer

    for p in xrange(playerCount):
        for z1 in xrange(zoneCount):

            if zoneOwner[z1] in (-1, p):
                # Player can spawn on neutral or owned zones
                result[z1, p] += playerAvailableUnits[p]

            for z2 in xrange(zoneCount):

                if zoneLinks[z1, z2] > 0 and not blockedMovesPerPlayer[p, z1, z2]:
                    # If z1 and z2 are connected and player can move from z1 to z2, adding units count on z1 to z2
                    result[z2, p] += unitCountPerPlayer[z1, p]
    return result
```

The problem is I can't use this function which takes around 30ms on each call and I know for sure it's rewritable as some numpy operations which should take less than 5ms to process.

Can someone help me on this one? Also is there a step by step process so that next time I could do it by myself? I've read numpy's documentation on arrays and indexing several times but it's far from being crystal clear and I just can't figure it out.

Edit: as requested, here are some random datas that can be used as sample:

```
zoneCount=8 ; playerCount=2

unitCountPerPlayer:
[[1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 3]
 [3 2]
 [1 2]
 [3 2]
 [0 2]
 [3 2]]

zoneOwner:
[ 1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1]

playerAvailableUnits:
[2 2]

zoneLinks:
[[0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]]

blockedMovesPerPlayer:
[[[False False False False False False False False]
  [ True False False False False False False False]
  [ True False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]
  [ True False False False False False False False]
  [ True False False False False False False False]]

 [[False  True False False False  True False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]
  [False  True False False False  True False False]
  [False  True False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False  True False False]
  [False False False False False  True False False]
  [False  True False False False  True False False]]]

get_max_units_on_zone_per_player():
[[ 1 14]
 [11  3]
 [15 18]
 [18 20]
 [10 10]
 [13  2]
 [12 12]
 [14 18]]
```

---

Copy/paste-able data:

```
zoneCount = 8
playerCount = 2

unitCountPerPlayer = np.array([[1,2], [1,3], [1,3], [3,2],
                               [1,2], [3,2], [0,2], [3,2]])

zoneOwner = np.array([1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1])

playerAvailableUnits = np.array([2,2])

zoneLinks = np.array([[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1], [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
                      [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                      [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]])

bmpp = [[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]],
        [[False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
         [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
         [False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False]]]
blockedMovesPerPlayer = np.array(bmpp)
```

Comment: Before premature optimisation, have you tried [`numba(nopython=True)`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html#nopython)?

Comment: I'm using conda python. I've already optimized a few functions like this (I mean for loops to numpy array operations) and each time I've gained impressive amount of milliseconds so actually I'd like to keep it this way. Also I'd like to improve my numpy skills rather than adding a decorator to my ugly functions :)

Comment: i completely understand. i still think trying `numba` is good anyway for benchmarking purposes (you need to know how good you are!)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the data?

Comment: @wwii Done. And blockedMovesPerPlayer has been computed from zoneLinks, zoneOwner and unitsCountPerPlayer so these are "realistic" datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update: Implementation of `numpy` way, avoiding `for` loops]**

Here is my *new* implementation of `get_max_units_on_zone_per_player()`:

```
def get_max_units_on_zone_per_player(unitCountPerPlayer, zoneOwner, playerAvailableUnits, zoneLinks, blockedMovesPerPlayer):
    result = unitCountPerPlayer.copy()
    result[zoneOwner < 0] += playerAvailableUnits
    _z1 = np.where(zoneOwner >= 0)
    result[_z1, zoneOwner[_z1]] += playerAvailableUnits[zoneOwner[_z1]]
    _p, _z1, _z2 = np.where(np.logical_and(zoneLinks > 0, np.logical_not(blockedMovesPerPlayer)))
    np.add.at(result, [_z2, _p], unitCountPerPlayer[_z1, _p])
    return result
```

I tested the two implementations with the following setting:

```
zoneCount = 100
playerCount = 1000
maxUnits = 500

unitCountPerPlayer = np.random.randint(0, maxUnits, size=(zoneCount, playerCount))
zoneOwner = np.random.randint(-1, playerCount, size=zoneCount)
playerAvailableUnits = np.random.randint(0, maxUnits, size=playerCount)
zoneLinks = np.random.randint(0, maxUnits, size=(zoneCount, zoneCount))
blockedMovesPerPlayer = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(playerCount, zoneCount, zoneCount), dtype=bool)
```

Here is the test result (with `%timeit`)

- fbparis's original implementation:

  7.27 s ± 10 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- my *new* implementation:

  645 ms ± 490 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Now I'm satisfied with the result. It shows the power of `numpy` way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, each function call is now less than 1ms!